# add css property to all div having same class in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple div with same class name.I want to apply css 'z-index:99' for all div which is having same class name in playbutton click.using jquery.Working only for first Play Button.I want to trigger for all playbutton click

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#playButton").click(function() {
    $(".close_icon").css('display', 'block');
    $(".video-container").css('z-index', '99');
    $(".videoThumbnail").css('z-index', '99');
  });

  $('iframe').load(function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find("head")
      .append($("<style type='text/css'>  iframe{height: 100%;left: 50%;min-height: 100vh;min-width: 100%; position: absolute;top: 60%;transform: translate(-50%, -60%);width: 100%;}  </style>"));
  });
  $(".close_icon").click(function() {
    $(".video-container").css('z-index', '0');
    $(".close_icon").css('display', 'none');
    $("#header").show();

  });
});

function callPlayer(frame_id, func, args) {
  if (window.jQuery && frame_id instanceof jQuery) frame_id = frame_id.get(0).id;
  var iframe = document.getElementById(frame_id);
  if (iframe && iframe.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'IFRAME') {
    iframe = iframe.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
  }
  if (iframe) {
    // Frame exists, 
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
      "event": "command",
      "func": func,
      "args": args || [],
      "id": frame_id
    }), "*");
  }
}
```

```css
#video-container {
  width: 100%;
}
.contentContainer {
  background: #5852a3;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #5852a3, #973695);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #5852a3, #973695);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(159, 74, 159, 0.5), rgb(112, 91, 168, 0.5));
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to right, rgba(88, 82, 163, 1) 0%, rgba(151, 54, 149, 1) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4% 0% 0% 0%;
}
.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="video-container" id="video-container">
    <h1> background 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="contentContainer">
    <div class="playVideo"><a href="javascript:void callPlayer(&quot;player&quot;,&quot;playVideo&quot;)" id="playButton">Play button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="video-container" id="video-container">
    <h1>background 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="contentContainer">
    <div class="playVideo"><a href="javascript:void callPlayer(&quot;player&quot;,&quot;playVideo&quot;)" id="playButton">Play button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is because the button is now hiding at the back of the background becasuse of its `z-index`. try setting the `z-index` of the button greater than the zindex of bg.

Comment: @Ron.Basco That may be the case, but the issue OP is describing (only one Play button functions) is because he's using the same ID for both buttons and trying to use ID as the jQuery selector.

Comment: You must use classnames instead of ID's on that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use same ID for multiple elements `#video-container` and `#playButton`, try with class.

```
$(".playButton").click(function() {
   $(".close_icon").css('display', 'block');
   $(".video-container").css('z-index', '99');
   $(".videoThumbnail").css('z-index', '99');
});
```

Comment: This answer will still apply css to all div in the DOM and not particular to div in which the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of giving `id="playButton"` to the playbutton. change it to `class="playButton"`. Since selecting Id jquery selects only one element

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".playButton").click(function() {
    $(".close_icon").css('display', 'block');
    $(".video-container").css('z-index', '99');
    $(".videoThumbnail").css('z-index', '99');
  });

  $('iframe').load(function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find("head")
      .append($("<style type='text/css'>  iframe{height: 100%;left: 50%;min-height: 100vh;min-width: 100%; position: absolute;top: 60%;transform: translate(-50%, -60%);width: 100%;}  </style>"));
  });
  $(".close_icon").click(function() {
    $(".video-container").css('z-index', '0');
    $(".close_icon").css('display', 'none');
    $("#header").show();

  });
});

function callPlayer(frame_id, func, args) {
  if (window.jQuery && frame_id instanceof jQuery) frame_id = frame_id.get(0).id;
  var iframe = document.getElementById(frame_id);
  if (iframe && iframe.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'IFRAME') {
    iframe = iframe.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
  }
  if (iframe) {
    // Frame exists, 
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
      "event": "command",
      "func": func,
      "args": args || [],
      "id": frame_id
    }), "*");
  }
}
```

```css
#video-container {
  width: 100%;
}
.contentContainer {
  background: #5852a3;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #5852a3, #973695);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #5852a3, #973695);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(159, 74, 159, 0.5), rgb(112, 91, 168, 0.5));
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to right, rgba(88, 82, 163, 1) 0%, rgba(151, 54, 149, 1) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4% 0% 0% 0%;
}
.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="video-container" id="video-container">
    <h1> background 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="contentContainer">
    <div class="playVideo"><a href="javascript:void callPlayer(&quot;player&quot;,&quot;playVideo&quot;)" class="playButton">Play button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="video-container" id="video-container">
    <h1>background 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="contentContainer">
    <div class="playVideo"><a href="javascript:void callPlayer(&quot;player&quot;,&quot;playVideo&quot;)" class="playButton">Play button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have defined multiple elements with same `id`. Id must be unique. Also you should find the `closest` div with class `content` and `find` elements within that to apply `css` to and not to all.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".playButton").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("div.content").find(".close_icon").css('display', 'block');
    $(this).closest("div.content").find(".video-container").css('z-index', '99');
    $(this).closest("div.content").find(".videoThumbnail").css('z-index', '99');
  });

  $('iframe').load(function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find("head")
      .append($("<style type='text/css'>  iframe{height: 100%;left: 50%;min-height: 100vh;min-width: 100%; position: absolute;top: 60%;transform: translate(-50%, -60%);width: 100%;}  </style>"));
  });
  $(".close_icon").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("div.content").find(".video-container").css('z-index', '0');
    $(this).closest("div.content").find(".close_icon").css('display', 'none');
    $("#header").show();

  });
});

function callPlayer(frame_id, func, args) {
  if (window.jQuery && frame_id instanceof jQuery) frame_id = frame_id.get(0).id;
  var iframe = document.getElementById(frame_id);
  if (iframe && iframe.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'IFRAME') {
    iframe = iframe.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
  }
  if (iframe) {
    // Frame exists, 
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
      "event": "command",
      "func": func,
      "args": args || [],
      "id": frame_id
    }), "*");
  }
}
```

```css
#video-container {
  width: 100%;
}
.contentContainer {
  background: #5852a3;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #5852a3, #973695);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #5852a3, #973695);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(159, 74, 159, 0.5), rgb(112, 91, 168, 0.5));
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to right, rgba(88, 82, 163, 1) 0%, rgba(151, 54, 149, 1) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4% 0% 0% 0%;
}
.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="video-container">
    <h1> background 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="contentContainer">
    <div class="playVideo"><a href="javascript:void callPlayer(&quot;player&quot;,&quot;playVideo&quot;)" class="playButton">Play button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="video-container">
    <h1>background 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="contentContainer">
    <div class="playVideo"><a href="javascript:void callPlayer(&quot;player&quot;,&quot;playVideo&quot;)" class="playButton">Play button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```